# ERROR A .NET 6 SDK for x86_64 was not found. Please install the latest x86_64 SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Tags: c#, .net, api, visual-studio-code

I got this error in VSCode C# extension. I already have SDK 6 and 7 installed on my computer and it persists in this error. Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5W7w.png)

I've already tried to install the requested sdks and restart the C# extension several times

dotnet --info results in

.NET SDK: Version: 7.0.102 Commit: 4bbdd14480

Ambiente de runtime: OS Name: Windows OS Version: 10.0.22000 OS Platform: Windows RID: win10-x86 Base Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\

Host: Version: 7.0.2 Architecture: x86 Commit: d037e070eb

.NET SDKs installed: 6.0.406 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk] 7.0.102 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App] Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App] Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found: x64 [C:\Program Files\dotnet] registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]

Environment variables: Not set

global.json file: Not found

Learn more: https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET: https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

The action that the error occurs is simply restarting vscode with the C# extension enabled

Comment: what action triggered the error?

Comment: Run `dotnet --info`, what do you get?